# Same variable or object in multiple functions

Tags: c++

Ok so I need help, how do I use the same variable i.e int x ; in multiple functions (void functions), i also need to use objects and i can't figure it out

```
class Jucator{
    public:
    int carteX; // <- j1
    int carteY; // <- j2
};
                  

int dez{
    Jucator j1;
    j1.carteX = 3 ; 
    cout << j1.carteX;
}

int main(){

    cin >> j1.carteX + 3; 

}
```

Comment: Reformat your code please?

Comment: `cin >> j1.carteX + 3;` what should this line do?

Comment: The variable `j1` exists in the scope of `dez`. In the scope of `main`, it is not created (and thus will result in the compiler telling you that the variable does not exist). Also, `dez` is never executed, not sure why you included it at all. Right now, executing the program would result in a single `cin` being executed, that is if the code was valid.

Comment: As a guess, do you realize that declaring a function like you do does not automatically execute the code, and that you'd have to call the function somewhere in `main`?

Comment: Yes, i do realize that i just needed some clearance for the functions so i can execute the program i want, i finished it

Answer (score 0):

> how do I use the same variable i.e int x ; in multiple functions

You can for example create a class. In the following example, the member variable `int x` is used in multiple void member functions:

```
class example {
    int x = 0;

public:
    void foo1() {
        x = 42;
    }
    void foo2() {
        std::cout << x;
    }
};
```

Comment: what's the difference between making the function public and not making it public?

Comment: @Nico Public functions can be called from outside the member functions.